# Recover holomorphic function from one component

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Let $k$ be fixed and suppose that $$v(\alpha,\beta)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c_j(\alpha)\beta^{2j+1}$$ is the imaginary (or the real, doesn't metter) part of an holomorphic function $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$, for some $c_j(\alpha)$. Is it true that $$f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{2k}a_jz^j,$$
for some $a_j\in\mathbb{C}$?
I've tried using the harmonicity of $v$ leading to the following conditions
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
c^{''}_{j}(\alpha)=-(2j+2)(2j+3)c_{j+1}(\alpha)\qquad j=0,...,k-2\\
c^{''}_{k-1}(\alpha)=0.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

Comment: No.  There are easy counterexamples already at $k=1$.

Comment: For example…?..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Analytic_functions
"All holomorphic functions are complex analytic"

Comment: Yes, that is pretty known, but how is it helpful in this situation?

Comment: Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ supposed to be $x$ and $y$?

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$? However, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ denote respectively the real and imaginary part of a complex number.

Comment: Notational Question: Why do you write $C_j'(\alpha)=c_j(\alpha)$? You mean the derivative, right?

Comment: Yes, I introduced the functions $C_j$ to have just one kind of function in the conditions.

Comment: It is **extremely easy** to come up with some $c_0$ that doesn't come from linear polynomial $f$.

Comment: @user10354138 Could you provide an explicit example? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: @calculatormathematical well, it was not necessary to introduce the primitives.

Comment: Is the question asking, "If the imaginary (or real) part of an entire function of $z$ is a real polynomial in the real and imaginary parts of $z$, is $f$ necessarily a polynomial?"

Comment: If my guess in the preceding comment is correct, then _yes_, for example by restricting to the real axis and using "permanence of analytic identities." <> Further, I'd tentatively guess that user10354138's prospective counterexamples are related to the converse: "Is every real polynomial the real or imaginary part of a complex polynomial?" whose answer is _no_.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, you are guessing it right. My main goal was proving that something was a complex polynomial of degree less or equal than $2k$, but what I had was a constrain on its imaginary part i.e. $v$ is a polynomial with only odd degree in $\beta$ up to $k-1$ degree. I was hoping that was enough to show that $f$ was itself a polynomial of degree less or equal than $2k$. I think that it is correct and the proof is contained in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here it is what I have found. 
In order for $v$ to be harmonic, the functions $c_j^{(k)}(\alpha)$ must be of the form
$$
c_j^{(k)}(\alpha)=(-1)^{j}(2k+1)\cdots(2j+2)\sum_{\eta=0}^{2k-2j-1}\frac{\alpha^\eta}{\eta!}s_{i+2j},
$$
for some complex numbers $s_l\in\mathbb{C}$. Indeed, it holds
$$
c'_j(\alpha)=(-1)^j(2k+1)\cdots(2j+2)\sum_{\eta=0}^{2k-2j-1}\frac{\alpha^{\eta-1}}{(\eta-1)!}s_{i+2j},
$$
$$
\begin{split}
c^{''}_j(\alpha)&=(-1)^j(2k+1)\cdots(2j+2)\sum_{\eta=0}^{2k-2j-1}\frac{\alpha^{\eta-2}}{(\eta-2)!}s_{i+2j}\\
&=-(2j+2)(2j+3)\left[(-1)^{j+1}(2k+1)\cdots (2(j+1)+2)\sum_{\eta=0}^{2k-2(j+1)-1}\frac{\alpha^\eta}{\eta!}s_{i+2(j+1)}\right]\\
&=-(2j+2)(2j+3)c_{j+1}(\alpha).
\end{split}
$$
It follows that $v(\alpha,\beta)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c_j^{(k)}(\alpha)\beta^{2j+1}$ is harmonic:
$$
\begin{split}
\Delta v(\alpha,\beta)&=\partial^2_\alpha v+\partial^2_\beta v=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c^{''}_j(\alpha)\beta^{2j+1}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(2j+1)(2j)c_j(\alpha)\beta^{2j-1}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}-(2j+2)(2j+3)c_{j+1}(\alpha)\beta^{2j+1}+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(2j+1)(2j)c_j(\alpha)\beta^{2j-1}\\
&=-\sum_{j=1}^k2j(2j+1)c_j(\alpha)\beta^{2j-1}+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(2j+1)(2j)c_j(\alpha)\beta^{2j-1}=0.
\end{split}
$$
From that, it is possible to show that the holomorphic function whose imaginary part is $v$ is
$$
f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{2k}\frac{(2k+1)!}{j!}s_{j-1}z^j.
$$
Indeed, by
$$
z^j-\bar{z}^j=2i\sum_{\eta=0}^{\lfloor \frac{j-1}{2}\rfloor}\binom{j}{2\eta+1}\alpha^{j-2\eta-1}(-1)^\eta\beta^{2\eta+1} 
$$
follows
$$
\begin{split}
\operatorname{Im}(f(z))&=\frac{1}{2i}(f(z)-f(\bar{z}))=\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{j=0}^{2k}\frac{(2k+1)!}{j!}(z^j-\bar{z}^j)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{2k}\frac{(2k+1)!}{j!}s_{j-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{\lfloor \frac{j-1}{2}\rfloor}\binom{j}{2\eta+1}\alpha^{j-2\eta-1}(-1)^\eta\beta^{2\eta+1}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\dfrac{(2k+1)!}{(2j)!}s_{2j-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{j-1}\binom{2j}{2\eta+1}\alpha^{2j-2\eta-1}(-1)^\eta\beta^{2\eta+1}+\\
&+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{(2k+1)!}{(2j+1)!}s_{2j}\sum_{\eta=0}^j\binom{2j+1}{2\eta+1}\alpha^{2j-2\eta}(-1)^{\eta}\beta^{2\eta+1}\\
&=(2k+1)!\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{\eta=0}^{j-1}\dfrac{(-1)^\eta s_{2j-1}\alpha^{2j-2\eta-1}\beta^{2\eta+1}}{(2\eta+1)!(2j-2\eta-1)!}+\\
&+(2k+1)!\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{j}\dfrac{(-1)^\eta s_{2j}\alpha^{2j-2\eta}\beta^{2\eta+1}}{(2\eta+1)!(2j-2\eta)!}.
\end{split}
$$
We can handle those two double sums for our purpose:
$$
\begin{split}
&\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{\eta=0}^{j-1}\dfrac{(-1)^\eta s_{2j-1}\alpha^{2j-2\eta-1}\beta^{2\eta+1}}{(2\eta+1)!(2j-2\eta-1)!}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^j \dfrac{(-1)^\eta s_{2j+1}\alpha^{2j-2\eta+1}\beta^{2\eta+1}}{(2\eta+1)!(2j-2\eta+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{(-1)^\eta s_{2j+1}\alpha^{2j-2\eta+1}\beta^{2\eta+1}}{(2\eta+1)!(2j-2\eta+1)!}=\sum_{\eta=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=\eta}^{k-1} \dfrac{(-1)^\eta s_{2j+1}\alpha^{2j-2\eta+1}\beta^{2\eta+1}}{(2\eta+1)!(2j-2\eta+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\eta=j}^{k-1} \dfrac{(-1)^js_{2\eta+1}\alpha^{2\eta-2j+1}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2\eta-2j+1)!}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{k-j-1} \dfrac{(-1)^js_{2\eta+2j+1}\alpha^{2\eta+1}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2\eta+1)!}
\end{split}
$$
and similarly
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{j}\dfrac{(-1)^\eta s_{2j}\alpha^{2j-2\eta}\beta^{2\eta+1}}{(2\eta+1)!(2j-2\eta)!}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{k-j-1}\dfrac{(-1)^js_{2\eta+2j}\alpha^{2\eta}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2\eta)!},
$$
so we get
$$
\begin{split}
\operatorname{Im}(f(z))&=(2k+1)!\left[\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{k-j-1} \dfrac{(-1)^js_{2\eta+2j+1}\alpha^{2\eta+1}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2\eta+1)!}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{k-j-1}\dfrac{(-1)^js_{2\eta+2j}\alpha^{2\eta}\beta^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!(2\eta)!}\right]\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j\dfrac{(2k+1)!}{(2j+1)!}\beta^{2j+1}\left[\sum_{\eta=0}^{k-j-1} \dfrac{s_{2\eta+2j+1}\alpha^{2\eta+1}}{(2\eta+1)!}+\sum_{\eta=0}^{k-j-1}\dfrac{s_{2\eta+2j}\alpha^{2\eta}}{(2\eta)!}\right]\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j\dfrac{(2k+1)!}{(2j+1)!}\beta^{2j+1}\sum_{\eta=0}^{2k-2j-1}\dfrac{s_{\eta+2j}\alpha^{\eta}}{\eta!}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c_j^{(k)}(\alpha)\beta^{2j+1}=v(\alpha,\beta).
\end{split}
$$